# Python: return self._regexp.findall(text) TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am getting this error when running my code
`return self._regexp.findall(text) TypeError: expected string or buffer.`

The problem is with tokenize in `words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(words) if len(e) >= 3]`

I am passing a list of strings like, `[('this is a sentence'),('this is also a sentence'),...]`
This works when I pass a tuple like this, `[('this is a sentence','sentiment'),('this is also a sentence','sentiment'),...]` so I'm not sure why its not parsing the list correctly. Any help would be great thanks!

```
tweets=[]
user_input=input('Tweets to be labeled:')

readdata=csv.reader(open(user_input,'r'))
for row in readdata:
    tweets.append(row)
Header = tweets[0]
tweets.pop(0)
Academic_test_tweets=tweets[:]
Tweets=[]
for (words) in tweets:
    bigram=[]
    bigram_list=[]
    words_filtered = [e.lower() for e in WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize(words) if len(e) >= 3]
    words_filtered=[re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1\1', e) for e in words_filtered if len(e)>=3]
    bigram_words=bigrams(words_filtered)
    for x in bigram_words:
        bigram.append(x)
    for (bi) in bigram:
        bigram_word=bi[0]+bi[1]
        bigram_list.append(bigram_word)
    list_to_append=words_filtered+bigram_list
    Tweets.append(list_to_append)
Academic_test_tweets_words=Tweets[:]
```

Comment: If it works with a list of t-uples, why don't you pass a list of 1-uple in your use case ?

Comment: I may have done that wrong but if I make a 1-tuple, [(['sentence'],),(['sentence two'],)...] I change to `for (words,sentiment) in tweets:`.... and it spits out i need more to unpack... Forgive me if Im missing this, I'm new to sentiment analysis, Im a physicist by training...

Comment: I solved it by changing the initial data input... `for [row] in readdata:` and it solved my problem... Thanks for the tip though it got me thinking about the data structure i was passing to my operations.